# Detect Server or Network Disconnects

Tags: ms-access, ado, vba

I have an Access application that is used as a TimeClock interface and to lookup pricing information. It is used on touchscreen computers and also on a Dell Latitude ST tablet which uses wireless exclusively.

The backend is SQL Server R2 2008 on a local Windows 7 "server" computer. I recently converted the application over to use forms bound to ADO recordsets in hopes that the application would be more resilient in the event that a disconnect occurs. I'm using a single, global ADO connection object. The tablet computer is configured to stay on all the time but it seems to lose connection occasionally. We could spend time troubleshooting the device and the network to make it more stable. However, I have hopes of being able to write my Access applications so they can be used over the WAN/Internet which will basically make network stability out of the picture and out of my control. I have chosen instead to focus on making this particular application (a fairly small one) more friendly with database disconnects and interruptions.

I've programmed a global function that basically checks to see if the ADO connection is open/connected. However, **if I disconnect the network, the connection object still shows that State = adStateOpen.**

I initially programmed a Test function to test the connection by opening a basic, single-record recordset. However, if the server was unavailable, this took way too long and seemed to cause a precipitation of errors beyond just the Test function (possibly some bad coding). I even changed connection TimeOut settings but it appeared that those timeouts were ignored since my test function would take about 15 (or was it 30) seconds to return in the event that the server really was unavailable.

I've now changed my function to close the connection every time and then re-open it. It seems so terribly inefficient but it is the only way I have found to make my application work properly after a server disconnect, without having to close out and open the application again. Server disconnects or network interruptions are actually very uncommon (basically non-existent), especially on the wired machines.

```
Public Function IsGConOpen(Optional bOpenCon As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    IsGConOpen = False

    If bOpenCon = True Then
        Dim sConString As String
        sConString = Config.ADOConString
        If sConString = "" Then
            Call InitGlobalSettings
            sConString = Config.ADOConString
        End If
        If sConString = "" Then Exit Function

        If gCon Is Nothing Then
            Set gCon = New ADODb.Connection
        Else
            If gCon.State = adStateOpen Then
                gCon.Close
            End If
        End If

        With gCon
            .Provider = "MSDataShape"
            .ConnectionString = sConString
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
            .ConnectionTimeout = 5
            .CommandTimeout = 5
            .Open
        End With
        If gCon.State = adStateOpen Then
            IsGConOpen = True
        End If
    Else
        If gCon Is Nothing Then
            IsGConOpen = False
        ElseIf gCon.State = adStateOpen Then
            IsGConOpen = True
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

[Here's a similar question (VB6 instead of Access) on a different forum.](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=178567) It appears to me that no solution was reached.

Is there a better way to manage my global ADO connection and detect server/network interruptions without having to close out the connection and reopen it every time?

Answer (score 0):

I always preferred carrying out a ping check on the server's IP to see if I had a connection, this way I can limit the amount of time to wait on my ping check to be as short as I like, I didn't originally write the following code but did adapt it to my needs:

```
Public Function SystemOnline(ByVal IPAdd As String) As Boolean

    Dim oShell, oExec As Variant
    Dim strText, strCmd As String

    strText = ""
    strCmd = "ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & IPAdd
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(strCmd)

    Do While Not oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        strText = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
        If InStr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
            SystemOnline = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Function
```

And then I call it as:

```
If Not SystemOnline("11.111.11.111") Then
    'Disconnected
Else
    'Connected
End If
```

Perhaps you could fire this at set intervals to see how the connection is looking.

Comment: This would certainly catch some cases but I don't think it would catch the case where a momentary disconnect happens and then the user tries to use the application. The connection would still show as adStateOpen, the server would ping fine, but the connection instance would be invalid. Or am I thinking incorrectly here?

Comment: @HK1 No, I agree, it's more a way of shortening down that 15 - 30 sec test period you mentioned so it could be run more often and hopefully catch any outage period's. In terms of catching the small interruptions i'm not sure if it can be done, but would like to know also so will start searching ^_^

Comment: Makes me wonder if there's any Windows "event" that occurs on a network adapter status change that could be subscribed to via the Win32 API. Here's an idea but it only applies to wireless connections. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=633165

Comment: @HK1 All I've been able to find is this (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Miscellaneous/Q_21671263.html) although I'm not sure if you are receiving those "Delayed Write Failed" errors.

Answer (score -1):

ADO is just another interface to ODBC which does not have a connection status. In ODBC you have the simple approach that you connect, do stuff, if stuff errors deal with the error.

The way I got round this problem in my MS Access program was to :-

1. Create connection
2. Do things ( select, updated, insert & delete )
3. If things error repeat process once and then display the error if it is still there.

This would work for basic statments however you may need to expand it a little further if you are sending multiple statments such as :-

1. Connect "con.open"
2. Begin transaction "con.BeginTrans"
3. Inset rows "con.Execute"
4. If all rows OK Commit the transaction "con.Commit"

The rows are only stored in the taget ODBC data source when you Commit so even if you get a network disconnection part way through inserting your rows this would that the data would not be stored. You could keep looping through the above if it's an automatted process or stop with a user error if the issue needs to be resolved before the code continues.

Comment: I don't think your suggestion will help much. We are binding forms to ADO recordsets.

Comment: I agree the above wouldn't help in that scenario however binding forms to any connection that could fail is a bad idea - you have no control over what happens when data is entered. The person who wrote our internal system here did the same - this was ok while everyone worked in the office. With poeple working from home on connections that could fail I stopped binding forms and hard coded the data read/write myself - thus getting round the probelm.

Comment: Bound forms aren't the problem. The problem I'm having would occur with bound or unbound forms.

Comment: The problem may be more apparent using a bound form, but using an unbound would be the same once you started reading/writing tables.